# Report file biding issue in VS2022

Tags: c#, rdlc, visual-studio-2022

I am writing a code to download pdf report from VS2022 API project. I have follow below steps to build project
1.The Microsoft Report builder create a new report file(rdlc).
2. Set the datasource and provide inline query to get data
3. The data set to report parameter and pie chart is showing
4. When I am runing the report from report builder its working and showing pie chart data
5. When I save rdlc and try to call my API project this throwing below error

> ------ Error -----
> -$exception   {"An error occurred during local report processing."}   Microsoft.Reporting.NETCore.LocalProcessingException
>
> ReportProcessingException: Cannot create a data reader for dataset
> 'DataSet1'.
>
> ----------End Error-------

```
string _CurrentDirectorypath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string _MapPath = _CurrentDirectorypath;
var path = Path.Combine(_MapPath, "wwwroot", "Report", "<NameReportFile>.rdl");

using var reportDefinition = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            

LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
report.LoadReportDefinition(reportDefinition);
var parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
           
parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("<Param1>", "<ParamValue>"));

try
{
    report.SetParameters(parameters.ToList());
    return new PDFFileInBytes
    {
        Content = report.Render("PDF"),
        FileName = "file.pdf",
        MimeType = "application/pdf"
    };
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    _logger.LogError(e, "Failed to Generate TokenReportEnglish.");
    throw;
}
```